# dynamically generate the headers in excel using spreadsheet gear

Tags: spreadsheet, spreadsheetgear

Example: Let say A,B,C are columns and 1,2,3 are rows in a sheet.For A column 1,2,3 rows need to merge display as single rows how using spreadsheet gear
  A     B     C
1
2 
3

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean about dynamically generating headers. What is your source of data? To merge columns or rows, you can use the Merge method of the IRange class.

```
workbookView1.ActiveWorksheet.Cells["A1:A3"].Merge()
```

Merging into one cell will keep the upper-left most data only.

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is use reflection to send a Enumerable type and convert it to DataTable.

```
 private static DataTable ConvertToDataTable(IEnumerable<T> enumerable)
        {
            var properties = TypeDescriptor.GetProperties(typeof(T));
            var table = new DataTable();
            foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                table.Columns.Add(prop.Name, Nullable.GetUnderlyingType(prop.PropertyType) ?? prop.PropertyType);
            foreach (var item in enumerable)
            {
                var row = table.NewRow();
                foreach (PropertyDescriptor prop in properties)
                    row[prop.Name] = prop.GetValue(item) ?? DBNull.Value;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
            return table;
        }
```

After that let the spreadsheet gear do its job.
Convert it to memory stream and then to byte[]

Pass the byte[] to FileContentResult